# Anonymours_User Creating Articles and Publishing Pages on Drupal 8

Tags: security, spam

It seems like our site's security has been compromised. We have some annoymous_users creating pages and publishing articles. They are all showing as unpublished, but it seems like there's dozens of pages created. We are running CiviCRM on Drupal 8. If someone can advise on the corrective actions required here that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: This question maybe belongs on https://drupal.stackexchange.com instead but check the permissions under People - Permissions.

Comment: (EDIT - just saw you said this was Anonymous, so ignore the rest but will leave in case is ever relevant for others) The only connection I could think to civicrm was if you had something like CiviGroup Sync or CiviMember Sync set up that was giving a contact who signed up a Drupal role that had too many permissions. Or worse, if you have people creating a Drupal User via a Profile and your Drupal Permissions are letting 'Authenticated' create content which would be a risky set up. HTH